# Animation for newly rendered elements, but not on page load

Tags: javascript, css, angular, animation, angularfire2

I'm subscribed to a Firebase real-time database so that when I submit something to it, it immediately renders in the view without any need for jQuery or ajax.

I'd like to animate the rendering of such elements, so that when a new element is added to the DOM its `div`'s `background-color` is green and slowly fades away. What I don't want is for all `div`s of this class to perform this animation on load.

I know how to do the former:

```
@keyframes green-fade {
    0% {background: rgb(173, 235, 173);}
    100% {background: none;}
}

.post-div {
   animation: green-fade 5s ease-in 1;
}
```

But of course this animation happens for this class any time it's rendered, including on load.

I'm interested in the "Angular 2 way" to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Angular 4.25 there's an easier way to do this: If you want to suppress an :enter animation on view initialization, just wrap it with the following animation:

```
template: `
  <div [@preventInitialChildAnimations]>
    <div [@someAnimation]>...</div>
  </div>
`,
animations: [
  trigger('preventInitialChildAnimations', [
    transition(':enter', [
      query(':enter', [], {optional: true})
    ])
  ]),
  ...
]
```

Comment: Updated the accepted answer as it addresses the current Angular version.

Comment: Not working for me in angular 4.2.4, the animations still happens at page load

Comment: The `[@someAnimation.done]` is still triggered making this solution not usable.

Comment: Can you please tell me where this @someanimation is registered in TS file? I am new to angular animation and facing the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest solution:

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'myComponent',
    template: '<div [@.disabled]="disableAnimations" [@someAnimation]="someValue">',
    animations: [trigger('someAnimation', [transition('* => *', [style({ transform: 'scale(1.1)' }), animate(250)])])]
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    disableAnimations: boolean = true;

    constructor() {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.disableAnimations = false;
    }
}
```

Reference:
https://angular.io/api/animations/trigger
(scroll to "disable animations")

Comment: This is the best solution. I tried the solution from Martin Cremer and it worked for first time load but when I navigated to a different component and then go back to original component animation got triggered.

Comment: It doesn't work. The compiler says: "ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '@.disabled: true'. Current value: '@.disabled: false'."

Comment: This was the only solution for me. I had to wrapped it in a (hacky) setTimeout to prevent the ExpressionChanged issue

Answer (score 3):

Add a trigger that checks the state of a item when it comes through the network. Here I'm triggering the animation when `itemState` is `new`.

```js
    trigger('itemState', [
      transition('* => new', animate(5000, keyframes([
        style({ backgroundColor: 'red', offset: 0 }),
        style({ backgroundColor: '*', offset: 1.0 })
      ]))),
```

Give your trigger a reference to the state of your item, and set it to null when the animation finishes.

```html
<div [@itemState]="someItem.itemState" (@itemState.done)="someItem.itemState=''">
```

Be sure to add an `itemState` property to your posts so that you can flag them as new!

Comment: If you are not using a local datastore of some sort, then you will have to make an API call on itemState.done Eg: `(@itemState.done)="someApiCall()` that sets that items state to `null` or `old` at an API level as well as setting it to `old` or `null` locally.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I'd just make the database call. Again, I'm using AngularFire, so the change in the item state on the database is reflected in real time.

Comment: This, of course, only shows the animation to users viewing the page as the post is made. Hmm, maybe something that makes the API call after an elapsed time?

Comment: Instead, I would personally create a firebase function that iterated through the date and times of posts in your database, and would set the `new` flag for each item's `itemState` property accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the life cycle hook AfterViewInit to activate the animation after the initial view rendering has finished.

https://embed.plnkr.co/5l1kf5lMLEXSE8pNzqik/

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let item of items" [@greenFade]="animate ? 'in' : null">
      {{item}}
    </div>

    <button (click)="addItem()">add</button>
  `,
  animations: [
    trigger('greenFade', [
      transition('void => in', [style({background: 'rgb(173, 235, 173)'}), animate('5s ease-in')])
    ])
  ]
})
class App implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef){}

  items: String = ['Item','Item','Item'];
  addItem(){
    this.items.push('Item');
  }

  animate: boolean;
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.animate = true;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this trigger the animation every time the view is rendered?

Comment: What makes you think so?
The animation of each item is triggered, when it's @greenFade attribute turns from void to 'in', in other words: If it's first value is 'in'. This happens just once. For initial items it doesn't happen at all. They turn from void to null, and then from null to 'in'.

Comment: Oh, you're right! Let me look into the benefits of this versus the accepted answer. I think the most obvious of course is that this doesn't require any values to be set on the backend. I suppose it depends on your use case.

Comment: This isn't working for me in Angular 4. I wonder if syntax has changed.

Comment: Try my new answer i just gave, it's referring to the latest Angular version and it's quite simple.

Comment: @MartinCremer   You are wrong. `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` causes the `ngAfterViewInit()` to run again and re-render every time!