# Angular. Is there a way to skip enter animation on initial render?

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

`:enter` animation is applied to an element when component is rendered the first time. Is there a way to prevent it?

Check [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ALlR9FhOn9N96WYlySKp?p=preview) for simple example of `width` animation:

```ts
transition(':enter', [
  style({width: 0}),
  animate(250, style({width: '*'})),
]),
```

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46186537/5155810

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just add an empty `:enter` animation to the view parent. In this case the initial child `:enter` animation will be disabled, but further animations will work.

Template:

```
<div @parent>
    <div @child>test</div>
</dif>
```

Animation:

```
trigger('parent', [
    transition(':enter', [])
])
trigger('child', [
    transition(':enter', [
      style({width: 0}),
      animate(250, style({width: '*'})),
    ]),
])
```

[Here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3417-using-no-op-transitions-to-prevent-animation-during-the-initial-render-of-ngfor-in-angular-5-2-6.htm) you can find more detailed explanation.

Comment: It works really well!

Answer (score 7):

There is the [void](https://angular.io/guide/animations#the-void-state) state for that. Which basically represents a `null` state.

In practice, that could look like this:

```
trigger('myState', [
  state('previous', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' })),
  state('current', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
  state('next', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' })),
  transition('void => *', animate(0)), // <-- This is the relevant bit
  transition('* => *', animate('250ms ease-in-out'))
])
```

What this means is that whenever an element *doesn't* have a state yet, and transitions into *any* state, it shouldn't animate.

So, in your case it could be written like this:

```
transition(':enter', animate(0))
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? Try the plunker. Firstly `:enter` is a shortcut for `void => *` so there is no sense in `void => :enter`. Secondly I already use `:enter` animation in the component it's the root of the problem, because input gets animated even on first draw.

Comment: `ERROR: The provided transition expression "void => :enter" is not supported`

Comment: Much more intuitive and semantic than the accepted answer. The other one is just a hack thta accidentally shows the intented behavior.

Comment: Quite the contrary: 'transition('* => *'` is a dirty hack, and accepted answer: 1) makes total sense; 2) works.