# Angular: Disable animation on page load

Tags: angular, animation

Angular 11.
I have a list of inputs (wrapped by a div, each.) with the ability to add an input using reactive forms, so whenever the user clicks a button to add an input, I push a control to the inputs array.

The behavior I want is that whenever the user dynamically adds an input, it will show with an animation, so I wrote this code:

```
  animations: [
trigger('input', [
  state('in', style({ opacity: 1 })),
  transition(':enter', [
    animate(
      '.3s ease-in',
      keyframes([
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        style({ opacity: 0.5 }),
        style({ opacity: 1 }),
      ])
    ),
  ]),
]),
```

].

Now, it works when adding a new input, but the animation also fires whenever the page loads, and by default, I have 3 inputs on the page.

How can I prevent the animation from firing on page load and to only happen whenever a new input is added?

I've tried adding a no-op animation on the parent (div), but it doesn't work.

```
    trigger(
        "blockInitialRenderAnimation",
        [
            transition( ":enter", [] )
        ]
    )
```

my HTML:

```
      <div
    *ngFor="let option of options.controls; let i = index"
    class="form-options"
  >
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Add option {{ i + 1 }}"
      [formControlName]="i"
      (focus)="onOptionFocus(i)"
      [@input]="'in'"
    />
  </div>
```

Comment: See also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50791299/16940

Comment: Note: I was able to get the 'no-op' animation to work. I noticed you didn't actually apply it to the DIV above in your example. Need to add `<div [@blockInitialRenderAnimation] ...>`. I did also notice that with both `[@blockInitialRenderAnimation]` and `[@.disabled]` the `(done)` handlers do run - so if that's doing something you want to prevent (such as scrolling the element into view) you'll need to find a different mechanism to stop it because not even `[@.disabled]` does

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use disable animation using [@.disabled](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#disabling-an-animation-on-an-html-element) binding. place this special binding on that element you want to disable animation. Then define isDisabled property inside your component then set isDisabled to true when you add form control

**component.html**

```
 <div [@.disabled]="isDisabled"
  *ngFor="let option of options.controls; let i = index"
  class="form-options" >
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Add option {{ i + 1 }}"
    [formControlName]="i"
    (focus)="onOptionFocus(i)"
    [@input]="'in'"
  />
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class SomeClass{
 isDisabled = true;

 addControl(){
  this.isDisabled = false;
  ....
 }
}
```